# Nomencl + KOMA style + flush right units = misalignment

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I am formatting my nomenclature list at the moment. I matched the style of the rest of the document via [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282162/mimicking-the-style-of-a-koma-script-section-heading-inside-a-nomenclature) and then attempted to flush the units right via [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167482/space-behind-unit-in-nomenclature-list). Details are below, thanks in advance.

---

MWE:

---

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% No extra line space between items
%\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

% Divide nomenclature into subgroups
\newlength\preGroupSkip
\setlength{\preGroupSkip}{3.5ex}
\newlength\postGroupSkip
\setlength{\postGroupSkip}{2.3ex}
\newcommand\groupHeading[1]{%
    \vspace{\preGroupSkip}%
    \item[\usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{section}#1]%
    \hspace*{\leftmargin}\vspace{\postGroupSkip}%
}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
        \groupHeading{Heading of group A}%
    }{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{%
        \groupHeading{Heading of group B}%
    }{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{%
        \groupHeading{Heading of group C}%
    }{}%
}
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}[#1]\nolinebreak\hspace*{2cm}\mbox{}}%
}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
% Define nomenclature entries
\nomenclature[a]{$m$}{mass \nomunit{$\si{kg}$}}
\nomenclature[b]{$\omega_{\mathrm{m}}$}{mechanical angular frequency \nomunit{$\si{Hz}$}}
\nomenclature[C]{$\omega_{\mathrm{el}}$}{electrical angular frequency \nomunit{$\si{Hz}$}}

\printnomenclature{}
dummy text
\end{document}
```

---

Resulting in:
[image: alignment issues]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert `\par` before `\vspace{\preGroupSkip}`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% No extra line space between items
%\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

% Divide nomenclature into subgroups
\newlength\preGroupSkip
\setlength{\preGroupSkip}{3.5ex}
\newlength\postGroupSkip
\setlength{\postGroupSkip}{2.3ex}
\newcommand\groupHeading[1]{%
    \par% <- added
    \vspace{\preGroupSkip}%
    \item[\usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{section}#1]%
    \hspace*{\leftmargin}\vspace{\postGroupSkip}%
}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
        \groupHeading{Heading of group A}%
    }{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{%
        \groupHeading{Heading of group B}%
    }{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{%
        \groupHeading{Heading of group C}%
    }{}%
}
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}[#1]\nolinebreak\hspace*{2cm}\mbox{}}%
}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
% Define nomenclature entries
\nomenclature[a]{$m$}{mass \nomunit{$\si{kg}$}}
\nomenclature[b]{$\omega_{\mathrm{m}}$}{mechanical angular frequency \nomunit{$\si{Hz}$}}
\nomenclature[C]{$\omega_{\mathrm{el}}$}{electrical angular frequency \nomunit{$\si{Hz}$}}

\printnomenclature{}
dummy text
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Explanation:**

Content of the `nls` file:

```latex
\begin{thenomenclature} 
\nomgroup{A}
  \item [{$m$}]\begingroup mass \nomunit{$\si{kg}$}\nomeqref {0.0}\nompageref{1}
\nomgroup{B}
  \item [{$\omega_{\mathrm{m}}$}]\begingroup mechanical angular frequency \nomunit{$\si{Hz}$}\nomeqref {0.0}\nompageref{1}
\nomgroup{C}
  \item [{$\omega_{\mathrm{el}}$}]\begingroup electrical angular frequency \nomunit{$\si{Hz}$}\nomeqref {0.0}\nompageref{1}

\end{thenomenclature}
```

So the issue can be simulated by the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item an entry \hfill first\label{first}
  \item an entry \hfill foo\label{foo}
  \vspace{10pt}
  \item an entry \hfill bar\label{bar}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\vspace` inserts the vertical space after the end of the current line. So there is a spurious space before this `\vspace`. To remove this spurious space, you can comment the end of the previous line

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item an entry \hfill first\label{first}
  \item an entry \hfill foo\label{foo}% <- removes the spurious space
  \vspace{10pt}
  \item an entry \hfill bar\label{bar}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

or you can use `\par` to finish the previous paragraph:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item an entry \hfill first\label{first}
  \item an entry \hfill foo\label{foo}
  \par
  \vspace{10pt}
  \item an entry \hfill bar\label{bar}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! worked great. Thanks. Care to explain why?

Comment: See my updated answer.